# x64 Assembly output r8d register with stdout

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

I am using x64 assembly to create a simple counter program. My aim is to get the program to go through the numbers from 1 to 10 and print them out using loops. I use r8b to store my number as it is only vary small and doesnt take up much storage. But i dont seem to be able to print out the numbers with the stdout. Neither can i change the value in it to something higher. I am on linux using nasm to assemble the code.
The code is as follows:

```
section .data


section .bss


section .text
 global _start

printrcx:
 mov rax,4  ; Write
 mov rbx,1  ; Standard output
 int 80h    ; Call kernel to run
 ret        ; Return out of proc

exit:
 mov rax,1  ; Exit call
 mov rbx,0  ; Code 0
 int 80h    ; Call kernel to run
 ret        ; Return if necessary

counter:
 push rcx
 mov rcx,r8b    ; Number
 mov rdx,2      ; 2 in length
 call printrcx

 cmp r8b, 10    ; Check if counter is at 10
 je exit        ; Exit if counter is at 10

 add r8b, 1     ; Add 1 to the counter
 jmp counter    ; If previous passed then
                ; jump back to counter

_start:

 mov r8b,1      ; Set counter to 1
 jmp counter    ; Start counter

 call exit
```

Comment: Read the relevant ABI documentation (SysV x86-64 in this case). You'll notice that you are **not supposed to use `int 0x80` for syscalls**. Also `r8` is caller-saved.

Comment: Also you need to convert it to text if you want to print it.

Comment: "$ man 2 syscall"  x86_64        rdi   rsi   rdx   r10   r8    r9    -
  x86_64     syscall              rax         rax    See below

Comment: @EOF : In the case of using IA32 `int 0x80` emulation (assuming it is enabled in the Linux kernel) in 64-bit code, the Kernel will preserve ALL registers with the exception of _RAX_ across `int 0x80`

Comment: @EOF what can i do if im not meant to use *int 0x80*

Comment: @OverloadedCore: Use `syscall` instead.